# Backtrace files and core files in Cavium-Octeon

Tags: backtrace, core-file

I am exploring information saved when a core hangs as in the following example:

user.emerg gs_app_main[1075]:
10@173805766276886: *** Begining crash dump for core 10 ***
10@173805773984802: *** Num cores left running 30 on coremask 0xfffffbfe ***
10@173805784192440: Core 10: Unhandled Exception. Cause register decodes to: address exc, load/fetch

I've searched the file system for backtrace* and core files.  I've discovered gcc can be used to generate a traceback but the application hardware does not include gcc in the Linux distribution.  Also, I find files with the name core* but not sure which are significant.

Answer (score 0):

1. OCTEON's Simple-Exec applications running bare-metal, don't have the
   ability to generate core or backtrace (saved as file).
2. Simple-Exec applications running in Linux user-space, can generate
   core. Although the capture and save will depend on a number of
   factors.

   If the core generation & capture is successful, then you will find the core file in the launch directory. You will have to use OCTEON gdb to examine the core file.

   In both cases, a traceback may be generated and spit out onto the Serial console, or reported to system log.

   If you have multiple *core files, then obviously the latest ones, or the ones corresponding to the crash time, are the relavant ones.
   Remember, you will have to use OCTEON native gdb on Target,  or  OCTEON-cross-built gdb on x86 HOST to examine the core files.